# Construct 3D image from multiple 2D images 

Tags: image-processing, graphics3d

My goal: How to  (1) construct 3D image for visualization.
        (2) how to write 3D array or image into binary raw file.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Mathematica?

Alternative_Answer for: (1)

```
slices={1,2,3,4,5};
ss = Map[ImageData, slices];
ListContourPlot3D[ss, Mesh -> None, Contours -> Automatic]
```

Comment: I think 1st part of the question was answered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering/6252#6252

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As to your first question:

There's a very nice example of [volume rendering with medical images in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html) (*Applications* section, item Volume Rendering) that seems to be applicable.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm wondering how to make [this](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/enhanced-2d-and-3d-graphics/volumetric-rendering-using-3d-textures.html).

Comment: Alternative approach: I was able to use an example by "halirutan":                                        filenames = FileNames[];                                ch[i_] := ImageData[Import[filenames[[i]]], "Bit"];        ss = Table[ch[i], {i, 1, 20}];               ListContourPlot3D[ss, Mesh -> Automatic]

Comment: @Szabolcs, here is my extremely slow volume rendered in mathematica, coordinates are slightly offset, https://gist.github.com/2840409. enjoy.