# How to show solid bodies using volumetric rendering?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

**Note:** This question was asked when Mathematica 8 was latest release.  Version 9 has built-in support for volume rendering through [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html).

---

There's an [example](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/enhanced-2d-and-3d-graphics/volumetric-rendering-using-3d-textures.html) on wolfram.com showing some medical data rendered in 3D.  Unfortunately there's no code, only an animation.

[image: Volume rendering]

Note that the data is shown as a solid three-dimensional body, not only 2D slices of it like in [the example on the doc page of `Texture`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6244/12).

Given a 3D texture, how can such a visualization of a solid 3D body be made using Mathematica?  You will find the volumetric data on the doc page of Texture, under Applications -> Volume Rendering.

I notice there's [something included with CUDALink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAVolumetricRender.html).  Unfortunately I can't try it (I don't have the hardware), but it looks quite different from the image I linked to above, so I think there must be an independent way to produce the image above.

[With Sjoerd's hardware (it's pretty cool, movements are totally smooth):]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

<sub>[Link to the MathGroup version of this post.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IAtirx3GicM/discussion)</sub>

Comment: I dropped the output of `CUDAVolumetricRender` you were talking about in your question. Please remove if you don't like it. It really is an impressive volumetric renderer.

Comment: This is an interesting question for me as well, since a number of the quaternion-based fractals are often rendered through this technique...

Comment: There is an OpenCLLink set of commands as well, which will work on ATI graphics cards:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/guide/OpenCLLink.html

Comment: @Sjoerd The `CUDAVolumetricRender` output is actually mouse-rotatable?

Comment: @Szabolcs It is. Moreover, it's amazingly fluent. You really see the power of CUDA acceleration here.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries how long did it take to render? I gave up after about 10 minutes because my CPU was getting a bit too hot to my liking. The "Installing data...." counter was at 30% by then.

Comment: @Heike Isn't that part just installing the CUDA tools?

Comment: @Szabolcs You're probably right. I'm trying Yu-Sung's code below at the moment, and the `CUDAResourcesInstall...` step seems to take a while (although not as long as before).

Comment: @heike A second at most, I'd say. But I had used it before. I think at first use it downloads over 100 MB of data and programs

Comment: @heike If you look at the directory sizes in [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6200/57) you'll see that CUDAlink is over 300MB. I'm not sure whether this is part of a basic install or is downloaded on demand. I guess it is the latter.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I managed to get is working in the end, but it isn't terribly responsive. I think my hardware is a bit outdated.

Comment: @heike I'd say on my PC it's even more responsive than rotating a low-polygon-count Graphics3D.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries On my system it's moderately responsive, but the kernel does seem to use a lot of cpu while the `CUDAVolumetricRender` is active. One of these days I'll get a proper desktop with a decent graphics card.

Comment: @heike I'm on a laptop with a fast (but not top of the line) mobile nVidia card. So, no need for a desktop.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, CUDALink is big in the default install.  The additional programs it downloads go into either `$BaseDirectory` or `$UserBaseDirectory` (not sure which), but the `$InstallationDirectory` is not touched.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Solution 1: Using 3D Texture with Polygons

The idea is to use `Polygon` with 3D texture supported by [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html), but it requires a bit of undocumented hack to make it smooth.

The original data set is from Stanford Graphics Group [website](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/).
The dataset that has been used is CThead, 8-bit tiffs ([download](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/cthead-8bit.tar.gz)).
Before proceed, make sure that you have a plenty of memory (~500MB would be enough). Also, if you don't have a good graphics card, turning off 3D antialiasing (through "Preference" menu) will be helpful.

#### Step 1

Download slices into Mathematica (it takes a long time...).

```
filename = "cthead-8bit.tar.gz"; (* Appropriate path to the downloaded file *)   
slices = Import[filename, #] & /@ Import[filename];
```

The images should look like this:

[image: slices]

#### Step 2

Let's apply some colors and transparency. We apply color function using [`Colorize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Colorize.html), then add alpha channel based on binarized image using [`ColorCombine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorCombine.html). Don't forget to specify the color space "RGB" (otherwise, the last channel will not be interpreted as opacity). Since it is a lot of slices, we will use [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelMap.html). I am reversing the result to match the orientation.

```
colored = 
  Reverse[ParallelMap[
    With[{img = #}, 
      ColorCombine[{
        Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], Binarize[img]
        }, "RGB"]] &, slices]];
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

We will combine them and pack them so that it will make a nice volumetric color dataset. Again, notice that option `DataReversed` is used to reverse the orientation.

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[ImageData[#, DataReversed -> True] &, colored]];
```

#### Step 3

Basically, we put a lot of polygons with textures coming from this volumetric color dataset. But to make it work rather smooth, you need to use undocumented option `BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> n}}` (n being some reasonable number). I won't go deep into how this option works, I will just say that this sets limit on rendering of translucent polygons.

Here is the main code to display it:

```
(* All are in 0-1 coordinates. *)
(* top is z-value for x-y cutaway. *)
(* right is x value for y-z cutaway. *)
(* step defines how many polygon slices will be inserted. Smaller -> more *)
With[{top = 0.4, right = 0.4, rpad = -.2, step = 0.01},
 Graphics3D[{
   EdgeForm[],
   Opacity[.4], (* Overall transparency of the textured polygons *)
   Texture[data], (* Set volumetric texture *)

   (* Bottom part up until the variable top *)
   With[{pts = Table[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, {z, 0, top, step}]},
     Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]
   ],

   (* Top part from top to 1, but from 0 to right in x direction *)         
   With[{pts = Table[{{x, 0, top}, {x, 1, top}, {x, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}}, {x, 0, right, step}]},
     Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]
   ],

   (* Cutaway decoration *)
   EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[.6, RGBColor[1., .8, .1]], Thick]], 
   FaceForm[], 
   Polygon[{{right, 0, top}, {1 + rpad, 0, top}, {1 + rpad, 1, top},
     {right, 1, top}, {right, 1, 1}, {right, 0, 1}}]
 },
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + rpad}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black, 
 RotationAction -> "Clip", SphericalRegion -> True, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], White], 
 ImageSize -> 4 {100, 100}, 
 (* Rendering option for smooth volumetric rendering *)
 BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1 + rpad, 1, .9}]
]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**Warning:** Be very careful of decreasing `step` or increasing `DepthPeelingLayers` and `ImageSize`. It will crash the Front End...

## Solution 2: Using CUDAVolumetricRender

It is a limited solution for the people who has CUDA capable graphics cards. Essentially, it will call [`CUDAVolumetricRender`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAVolumetricRender.html) function which is a part of *CUDALink*.

#### Step 0

We need to load the *CUDALink* package.

```
<<CUDALink`
```

The following line will make it sure that you get the latest CUDA paclet.

```
CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]
```

It takes a long time to download full paclet, so if you are sure that your CUDA distribution is up to date (`CUDAResourcesInstall[]` returns 8.0.4.2, as of 5/31/2012), then you can skip this step.

#### Step 1

Download slices into Mathematica (the same as above).

```
filename = "cthead-8bit.tar.gz"; (* Appropriate path to the downloaded file *)   
slices = Import[filename, #] & /@ Import[filename];
```

#### Step 2

Create a volume data suitable for the `CUDAVolumetricRender`. First, the data should be a packed integer array with depth 3, each element should range from 0 to 255 (0 being background). Since original data is already in 0-255 range (8-bit TIFF), you can use `ImageData[..., Automatic]` to take original values out. Otherwise, you can use `ImageData[..., "Byte"]` to enforce it to be in byte range.

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[ImageData[#, Automatic] &, slices]];
```

Here is a slight problem. Apparently there is a bug. To render $d \times h \times w$ voxel data, you need to partition it again, so that the data would have $h \times w \times d$ dimension. We are not talking of transposing it, instead, literally we just need to change dimension, without touching data order. It is hard to explain and no need to understand, so I will just provide a conversion function here:

```
Clear[prepareCUDAVolumeData];

prepareCUDAVolumeData::arg = 
  "The argument should be an integer array of depth 3.";

prepareCUDAVolumeData[array_] /; ArrayQ[array, 3, IntegerQ] := 
  Module[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Dimensions[array];
   Developer`ToPackedArray[
    Partition[#, x] & /@ Partition[Flatten[array], x*z]]];

prepareCUDAVolumeData[___] /; (Message[prepareCUDAVolumeData::arg]; 
    False) := Null;
```

#### Step 3

Now, we are ready. Let's try this:

```
CUDAVolumetricRender[prepareCUDAVolumeData[data]]
```

Here is the result (with some parameter tweak):

[image]

The problem with this approach is that you don't have much flexibility except what is given by the interface.

**Note:** The volume rendering support in Mathematica 8 is quite limited (without *CUDALink*). Technically, it is not really volumetric rendering in traditional sense. A proper volumetric rendering requires a transfer function which converts accumulation of density values into certain color per each pixel. Here, we are mimicking the effect by using false coloring and alpha blending. The *CUDALink* volume rendering is a *real* deal, but you don't really need CUDA as long as graphics cards supports shader language (which is mostly true nowadays).

**Note 2:** You can expect much improved (and proper) volumetric support in the future... ;)

Comment: Could you comment on how one would do this using `CUDALink`?

Comment: @rcollyer , `CUDAVolumetricRender` is in the documentation ([link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAVolumetricRender.html)), although it is a canned function. You don't really have much freedom except what's offered there through the interface... (also, you sometimes get memory allocation error).

Comment: I've looked at the documentation, but it only gives examples involving data already in the raw format. I'm more interested in how one would take a set of slices, as above, and use `CUDAVolumetricRender`.

Comment: Added the solution using `CUDAVolumetricRender`.

Comment: This is really great ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Yu-Sung, do you know if CUDALink is supported on the new retina Macbook Pros? I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB card, done `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]`, and `CUDADriverVersion[]` returns 5.0.17. Yet `CUDAQ[]` returns `False`... anything else I should be doing or is it just not supported yet?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't got hold of retina Macbook, so I can't answer... But I will ask around and see if I can find some answer for you.

Comment: OK. Update (suggestions from Wolfram TS and CUDA developer): 1) Make sure that you have the most recent dev driver from [Nvidia](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/drivers/devdriver_4.2.10_macos.dmg). 2) Retina has dual GPU, and apparently Intel HD4000 is set by default. Make sure that you set NVidia one as default (I don't know how... I don't have the machine :) ).

Comment: This seems to be a related article from Apple (about switching the GPU): http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4110

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Sorry for the late response, but I saw these only now. I wasn't pinged about these because you didn't explicitly ping me with @ and I casually decided to check :) Anyway, the trick was to force it to use Nvidia all the time as in the support article. That, with the latest CUDA (5.02), `CUDAQ[]` gives `True`. However, running example 2 above gives the error: `LibraryFunction::memerr: -- Message text not found -- (oVolumetricRendering_Initialize) >>` when calling `CUDAVolumetricRender` and the output is not displayed... any ideas? The doc page it leads to doesn't say much

Answer (score 6):

Here is my extremely slow volume rendering solution.  It is based on placing a `Cuboid[]` for each voxel of the data.

I switched from `MapThread` to `ParallelMap` as for some reason `MapThread` cannot be parallelized.

```
slices = Import["https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/slicedata.wdx"]
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[ImageData, slices]];

(*downsampling slices*)
resized = ImageResize[#, 64] & /@ slices;
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[ImageData, resized]];

(*3D*)
dims = Dimensions@data;
coordswithdata = Table[{data[[x, y, z]], {x, y, z}}, {x, 1, dims[[1]]}, {y, 1, dims[[2]]}, {z, 1, dims[[3]]}];
cubes = {Hue @@ #1, EdgeForm[], Cuboid@#2} &
output = ParallelMap[cubes @@ # &, coordswithdata, {3}];
Graphics3D@output
```

When I tried to rotate the view Mathematica crashed so here is an ugly screenshot, but it works (sort of)!

[image: screenshot]

```
(*2D*)
dims = Dimensions@data[[45]];
coordswithdata = Table[{data[[45, x, y]], {x, y, 1}}, {x, 1, dims[[1]]}, {y, 1, dims[[2]]}];
cubes = {Hue @@ #1, EdgeForm[], Cuboid@#2} &
output = ParallelMap[cubes, coordswithdata, {2}];
Graphics3D@output
```

"[image: Mathematica graphic]"

Comment: This took 7 minutes of kernel time and 1G of kernel memory, then it died in swapping while transferring the data to the front end.  Can you post a screenshot just to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: @Szabolcs, screenshots uploaded.

Comment: A couple of things — This still isn't using the actual 3D texture, but simply uses `Hue` to fake colour it. Secondly this won't be smooth and will eat up memory and resources like crazy even for a rough output. Compared to this, Yu-Sung's was fluid. In fact, I have a very similar deleted answer, and the main issue there too was memory and roughness. The missing ingredient is the undocumented `DepthPeelingLayers` that Yu-Sung showed.

Comment: @R.M. You are right, it is very slow and memory intensive. I left it up there in case anyone wanted to see or improve upon it, no doubt, Yu-Sung's answer is much better. However, this doesn't fake the 3D texture using `Hue` it renders each voxel using the hue value given in the dataset including the opacity so the low-intensity (z) voxels are translucent.