# How to make 3d solid volume from set of images

Tags: image-processing, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show solid bodies using volumetric rendering?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering)

I have a set of images, and I want to construct a z-stack, then reconstruct it to a 3d volume.

Comment: Is that any different than what is done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6247/57)?

Comment: It's a solid volumetric render. If you have the hardware you can try the example right away. Your question is not about *saving* 3D solid geometry. If you want *that* I suggest you ask it in a separate question, but be very specific about what you want. By the way, since you indicate that your question is not different from what was asked in the question I linked to, I'm going to vote to close as duplicate.