# How to draw cylinders inside a cube

Tags: graphics

I want to create the following graphic[image]
(ignore the unit vectors).

What I do is the following (not the most elegent and smart way I guess:-)!):

1) Use the code below to generate randomly distributed but not intersecting circles (I adopt the code from this forum but I don't remember the thread. Actually I learnt from my recent posts other ways to do this.)

```
distinct[n_, r_] := 
 Module[{d, f, p}, d = {Disk[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], r]};
  Do[f = RegionDistance[RegionUnion @@ d];
   While[p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]; f[p] < r];
   d = Append[d, Disk[p, r]], {n - 1}];
  d]
```

Generate the circles

```
circles = distinct[75, 0.1];
```

Generate the respective cylinders which have this circles as cross sections.

```
cylinders = 
  Graphics3D[{Cyan, EdgeForm[Thick], 
    Cylinder[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], -3}, {#[[1]], #[[2]], 3}}, 0.1] & /@ 
     Map[First, fibers]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, Automatic}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];
```

Generate the parallelepiped.

```
par= Graphics3D[{Blue, EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0.6], 
    Cuboid[{-1, -1, -3}, {1, 1, 3}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];
```

And adding them altogether

```
Show[{cylinders, par}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, Automatic}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

But the result is quite unsatisfactory.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit related: [How to plot contours in the faces of a cube](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38656/4678)

Comment: You can find almost everything here:-)!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Firstly, let us generate some set of random circles with `findPoints` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2603/4678) answer

```
findPoints = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {low, _Real}, {high, _Real}, {minD, _Real}},
    Block[{data = RandomReal[{low, high}, {1, 2}], k = 1, rv, temp}, 
    While[k < n, rv = RandomReal[{low, high}, 2];
     temp = Transpose[Transpose[data] - rv];
     If[Min[Sqrt[(#.#)] & /@ temp] > minD, data = Join[data, {rv}];
      k++;];];
    data]];

npts = 150;
r = 0.03;
minD = 2.2 r;
low = 0;
high = 1;

pts = findPoints[npts, low, high, minD];
g2d = Graphics[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.8], 
   EdgeForm@Directive[Thickness[0.004], Black], Disk[#, r] & /@ pts}, 
  PlotRange -> {{low, high}, {low, high}}, Background -> Lighter@Blue]
```

[image]

### Method 1: Texture

We can simply use this graphics as a texture of the cube

```
pad = 0.1;
coords = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
cube = Polygon[{{1, 3, 7, 5}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {5, 7, 8, 6}, {7, 3, 4, 
     8}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {6, 8, 4, 2}}];
vtc = pad + (1 - 2 pad) coords[[;; , {1, 3}]];

Graphics3D[{Texture[g2d], 
  GraphicsComplex[coords, cube, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

### Method 2: MeshRegion

I'm appreciate many upvotes so I want to expand my answer and add a more general approach. *Mathematica* has very powerful (and still very limited) region functions.

Let's try to use some interesting 2D mask:

```
mask = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .02}] &@
   ImplicitRegion[
    0.1 < x < 0.9 && 0.1 < y < 0.9 + 0.05 Sin[20 x], {x, y}];
r2d = DiscretizeGraphics[g2d, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
inside = RegionIntersection[r2d, mask]
```

[image]

Then I find the edge and points on the edge. Unfortunately `RegionIntersection` doesn't work with lines and points. Here is workaround

```
edge = DiscretizeRegion@*Line@*Intersection @@ 
   Round[{Sort /@ 
      MeshPrimitives[RegionIntersection[r2d, mask], 1][[;; , 1]], 
     Sort /@ MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[r2d, mask], 1][[;; , 
       1]]}, .0001];
points = DiscretizeRegion@*Point@*Intersection @@ 
   Round[{MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[r2d, mask], 0][[;; , 1]], 
     MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[mask, r2d], 0][[;; , 
      1]]}, .0001];
```

Then I want to make [`RegionProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html) to create 3D regions from corresponding 2D regions. I also have to use hand-written workaround

```
regionProduct[reg_, join_: True, y1_: 0, y2_: 1] := 
  Module[{n = MeshCellCount[reg, 0]}, 
   MeshRegion[Join @@ (ArrayFlatten@{{#[[;; , ;; 1]], #2, #[[;; , 2 ;;]]}} &[
         MeshCoordinates@reg, #] & /@ {y1, y2}), {MeshCells[reg, _], 
     MeshCells[reg, _] /. p : {__Integer} :> p + n, 
     If[join, MeshCells[reg, _] /. {(Polygon | Line)[
          p_] :> (Polygon@Join[#, Reverse[#, 2] + n, 2] &@
           Partition[p, 2, 1, 1]), 
        Point[p_] :> Line@{p, p + n}}, ## &[]]}]];
mask3d = regionProduct@mask;
inside3d = regionProduct[inside, False];
edge3d = regionProduct@edge;
points3d = regionProduct@points;
```

The result is impressive

```
toGC[reg_, dim_] := GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@reg, MeshCells[reg, dim]];

Graphics3D[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.7], toGC[inside3d, 2], 
  EdgeForm[], toGC[edge3d, 2], toGC[points3d, 1], Lighter@Blue, 
  GeometricTransformation[toGC[mask3d, 2], 
   ScalingTransform[0.999 {1, 1, 1}, RegionCentroid@mask3d]]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Also with transparency:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.7], 
  toGC[regionProduct[RegionBoundary@inside, False], 1], EdgeForm[], 
  toGC[regionProduct@inside, 2], toGC[edge3d, 2], toGC[points3d, 1], 
  Blue, Opacity[0.03], 
  GeometricTransformation[toGC[mask3d, 2], 
   ScalingTransform[0.999 {1, 1, 1} #, RegionCentroid@mask3d] & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.01]]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}]
```

[image]

I hope future versions will do it more automatically.

Comment: Wow! Great! But what are these gray (?) shapes on the upper face of the cube?

Comment: @dimitris, it is a cross section of the circle near its edge. Circles have black edge with nonzero thickness. After texture interpolation it smooths and becomes gray. You can find more accurate random realization of circles.

Comment: Ok. I run your code and see that for other generated circles we do not have this Țside-effectȚ. Thank you very much for your amazing workaround (and the quick response!).

Comment: Can you explain `coords[[;; , {1, 3}]]`? I see it yields `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}`, but I don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke It's projection of coordinates to x-z plane

Comment: @ybeltukov: Thanks!

Comment: Very nice, indeed.

Comment: @ybeltukov: I think I will need much more to understand the code than the time the time I spent to create the original drawing in Word:-)! Your approach is simply amazing!

Comment: Can you explain me the `cube=Polygon[{{1, 3, 7, 5}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {5, 7, 8, 6}, {7, 3, 4, 8}, {3, 
   1, 2, 4}, {6, 8, 4, 2}}]` the chosen values and also the fourth argument of the inner lists?

Comment: Also, how did you achieve this view from "in front"? Especially, the second graphic (with the transperacy) is not roated easily so it would be good to specify in advance the "in front view".

Comment: @dimitris It is number of `coords`, which makes faces of the cube. You are right, I rotated the graphics manually. Now `regionProduct` expands in the y direction for the proper orientation.

Comment: Very very nice +1

Comment: Very nice. Just a little remark for method 1 figure: the `pad` you took is a little bit too large, because the face of the cube does not look like `g2d`.  `pad=0.0015` gives very good result.

Comment: @SquareOne This padding was chosen to be sure to obtain *uniform* random distribution of circles. Compare edge circles in `g2d` and in the desired picture.

Answer (score 7):

Although I think that some of the options presented on the other answers are better, this one is probably the one with the shortest code on the 3D aspect:

Starting from any of the 2D generated graphics, from the other answers, hereafter named `g2d`:

```
Image3D[{Rasterize[g2d]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

and a lot of tweaking is possible with the `Image3D` options.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think my collegue who is afraid of large codes will love this solution:-)!

Comment: @dimitris and I just reduced a few more characters... (I recently participated on the one-liner... :-)

Comment: I don't know why but I cannot reproduce your result. I got error message: `Image3D::imgarray: The specified argument...`

Comment: @dimitris  You have to put the image inside a list. Have you done that? `{g2d}` I'm on 10.3.0. If it doesn't work, try to repeat the image `{g2d, g2d}`

Comment: Same error message with `Image3D[{g2d}, BoxRatios -> 1]` & `Image3D[{g2d, g2d}, BoxRatios -> 1]`. Strangely the Documentation Center says **Introduced in 2012 (9.0) | Updated in 2014 (10.0)** for this function (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html)

Comment: Same weird behavior with a clear Kernel...

Comment: The complete error message.  `Image3D::imgarray: The specified argument {figure},{figure} should be an array of rank 3 or 4 with machine-sized numbers. >>. The error message is not documentated.

Comment: @dimitris OK. I made a shortcut in my reasoning. Starting from a raster! `Image`. You are probably using a `Graphics`.

Comment: Hi. I am not in front of Mathematica now. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Even with `Image3D[{Rasterize[g2d]}, BoxRatios -> 1]` the message appears again.

Answer (score 4):

How about `DensityPlot3D` or `ListDensityPlot3D`.

```
DensityPlot3D[
 Sin[\[Pi] z] + Cos[\[Pi] x], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4.5, 4.5}, 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, If[f > 1, 1, .5]], OpacityFunctionScaling -> False,  
 ColorFunction -> Function[f, If[f > 1, Gray, Blue]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: If you notice I want the cylinders randomly distributed. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: It is an interesting idea. May be you can use `NearestFunction` with some random points.

Comment: @ybektukov: You are right. The solution of Edmund is very nice and I agree it can be further extended.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing new here. Just a workaround following the new things I learn from ybeltukov amazing answer (and copy them:-)!).

Use the code below to generate randomly distributed but not intersecting disks

```
distinct[n_, r_] := 
 Module[{d, f, p}, d = {Disk[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2], r]};
  Do[f = RegionDistance[RegionUnion @@ d];
   While[p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]; f[p] < r];
   d = Append[d, Disk[p, r]], {n - 1}];
  d]

disks // Clear
SeedRandom[159]
disks = distinct[75, 0.03];

g2d = Graphics[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.8], 
   EdgeForm@Directive[Thickness[0.004], Black], disks}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Background -> Lighter@Blue]
```

Texture...

```
pad = 0.1;
coords = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
cube = Polygon[{{1, 3, 7, 5}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {5, 7, 8, 6}, {7, 3, 4, 
     8}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {6, 8, 4, 2}}];
vtc = pad + (1 - 2 pad) coords[[;; , {1, 3}]];
```

and the 3D final drawing...

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[g2d], 
  GraphicsComplex[coords, cube, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

[image]

And a bit of cylinders now...(do not expect something advanced here:-)!)

```
mycylinders = 
  Cylinder[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], -3}, {#[[1]], #[[2]], 3}}, 0.03] & /@ 
   Map[First, disks];

cub = Graphics3D[{FaceForm@Blue, Opacity[0.2], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, -3}, {1, 1, 3}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[{Graphics3D[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.7], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
    BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}, 
    mycylinders}], cub}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

I guess the final drawing can be made much better...

Comment: Just a side note: `BaseStyle -> {RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 100}}` is a specific option to plot complicated semi-transparent graphics (e.g. in [quasi-volumetric rendering](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6252/4678)).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will modify it!