# find the maximum number of not intersecting circles inside an ellipse

Tags: graphics, random, packing

```
$Version
```

> "10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"

(Sequel to [98724](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98724/how-to-draw-cylinders-inside-a-cube) and [99345](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99345/how-to-draw-cylinders-inside-a-cylinder))

(I use codes originally created by Andy Ross, ybeltukov and J.M.).

I am wondering if one can find the maximum number of randomly generated circles inside a given ellipse.

Using the function `findPoints` defined below

```
findPoints = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {low, _Real}, {high, _Real}, {minD, _Real}},
    Block[{data = RandomReal[{low, high}, {1, 2}], k = 1, rv, temp}, 
    While[k < n, rv = RandomReal[{low, high}, 2];
     temp = Transpose[Transpose[data] - rv];
     If[Min[Sqrt[(#.#)] & /@ temp] > minD, data = Join[data, {rv}];
      k++;];];
    data]];
```

and taking

```
npts = 150;(*number of points*)
r = 0.03;(*radius of the circles*)
minD = 2.2 r;(*minimum distance in terms of the radius*)
low = 0; (*unit square*)
high = 1;(*unit square*)

ep = With[{a = 2/5, b = 1/2}, 
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
    ParametricRegion[(low + high) {1, 1}/2 + 
      c ({a Cos[t], b Sin[t]} + 
         r Normalize[Cross[D[{a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}, t]]]), {{c, 0, 
       1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}]];

SeedRandom[159];
pts = Select[findPoints[npts, low, high, minD], RegionMember[ep, #] &];
g2d = Graphics[{Disk[#, r] & /@ pts, Circle[{1/2, 1/2}, {2/5, 1/2}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

we get

[image]

and 72 circles (disks) are lying within the ellipse.

```
pts // Length
(*72*)
```

Now I increase progressively the number `npts`.

```
npts = 160;

SeedRandom[159];
pts = Select[findPoints[npts, low, high, minD], 
   RegionMember[ep, #] &] // Length
(*80*)

npts = 170;

SeedRandom[159];
Timing[(pts = Select[findPoints[npts, low, high, minD], 
   RegionMember[ep, #] &] )// Length]
(*{8.23561, 87}*)

npts = 171;
r = 0.03;
minD = 2.2 r;
low = 0;
high = 1;

SeedRandom[159];
Timing[(pts = 
    Select[findPoints[npts, low, high, minD], 
     RegionMember[ep, #] &]) // Length]

(*{12.7237, 87}*)
```

I guess that we have reach a plateau as it is clear below.

```
    g2d = Graphics[{Disk[#, r] & /@ pts, Circle[{1/2, 1/2}, {2/5, 1/2}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

My question now is how we can use Mathematica in order to extract the maximum number of not intersecting circles withing an ellipse?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem consists of two questions: how to determine if circle is inside the ellipse and how to maximize the number of circles?

### 1. Circle is inside the ellipse?

Let us show that the region of possible circle centers are bounded by a [parallel curve of degree 8](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseParallelCurves.html).

```
ClearAll[x, y, a, b, r];
eq1 = Simplify[RegionDistance[Disk[{0, 0}, {a, b}], {x, y}]^2 == r^2, 
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 > 1]
```

[image]

`RegionDistance` gives distance outside the ellipse, but it doesn't matter now. Now we can eliminate `Root`:

```
pointInEllipse[x_, y_, a_, b_] = 1 - x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2;
circleNotIntersectEllipse[x_, y_, a_, b_, r_] = 
 FullSimplify@*Subtract @@ 
  Eliminate[{eq1 /. _Root -> q, 
    FirstCase[eq1, Root[eq_, _] :> eq@q == 0, , ∞]}, q]
```

[image]

The last formula is positive when the circle doesn't intersect the ellipse. Now we can visualize the obtained region for different values of the circle radius

```
a = 2;
b = 1;
RegionPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[circleNotIntersectEllipse[x, y, a, b, r] > 0 && 
    pointInEllipse[x, y, a, b] > 0, {r, 0.2, 1, 0.2}], {x, -1.1 a, 
  1.1 a}, {y, -1.1 b, 1.1 b}, PlotPoints -> 60, Epilog -> Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There are some glitches, but they appear only for unreasonable big values of the radius.

## 2. Maximize the number of circles

I think that the circle packing is the good starting point

```
r = 0.1;
{x, y} = Transpose@Join[Tuples@{##}, Tuples@{# + r, #2 + Sqrt[3] r}] &[
     Range[-#, #, 2 r], Range[-#, #, Sqrt[3] 2 r]] &@Max[a, b];
RegionPlot[circleNotIntersectEllipse[x, y, a, b, r] > 0 && 
  pointInEllipse[x, y, a, b] > 0, {x, -1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {y, -1.1 b, 1.1 b}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, Epilog -> {Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], Point@Transpose@{x, y}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Points inside the blue region show possible circle centers. Now we have to find the best translation and orientation of the circle packing

```
transform[x0_, 
   y0_, φ_] := {{Cos[φ], Sin[φ]}, {-Sin[φ], 
      Cos[φ]}}.{x, y} + {x0, y0};
inside[x0_, y0_, φ_] := 
 UnitStep[circleNotIntersectEllipse[##, a, b, r], pointInEllipse[##, a, b]] & @@ 
  transform[x0, y0, φ]
func[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, φ_?NumericQ] := 
  Total@inside[x0, y0, φ];

{x1, y1, φ1} = 
 NArgMax[func[x0, y0, φ0], {x0, y0, φ0}]
(* {-0.327895, 0.286679, -0.290644} *)

circles = 
  Pick[Transpose@transform[x1, y1, φ1], inside[x1, y1, φ1], 1];
Length@circles
(* 160 *)
```

The number of circles is close to the theoretical prediction from Thies Heidecke's answer

```
π/2/Sqrt[3] a b/r^2
(* 181.38 *)
```

Finally, we can plot the result packing

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], Lighter@Blue, Disk[#, r] & /@ circles}]
```

[image]

May be there is possibility to insert one or two circles more, but it requires much more advanced technique.

P.S. The order of evaluation matters. For simplicity I omit some scoping constrictions.

Comment: The first equation presented is in fact the implicit Cartesian equation for the parallel of an ellipse. (For comparison, the code used by the OP (based on a previous answer of mine) used a parametric representation.)

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, I didn't know the name of the curve. I searched it as "constant distance curve" with no avail. However, my implicit formula explicitly counts points inside.

Answer (score 6):

Solving this exactly is a hard or at least nontrivial problem if you want to prove the exact optimal number. Two things that are easier and still interesting in practice often are:

### Getting an upper bound for the number of circles in an ellipse

From [Circle Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) we know that $$\eta=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$$ is the highest possible density that can be achieved if the shape would optimally allow for tightly fitting circles inside of it. That directly leads to an upper bound of:

```
ellipsearea=\[Pi] a b
optimaldensity=\[Pi]/(2 Sqrt[3])
circlearea=\[Pi] r^2
effectiveusablearea=ellipsearea*optimaldensity
upperboundnrofcircles=Floor[effectiveusablearea/circlearea]
```

$$\lfloor\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{a b}{r^2}\rfloor$$

### Approximate solution through simulation

The other thing we could do is come up with a method that tries to get close to the optimum using some kind of heuristic, e.g. greedy filling of the area with touching circles or what would be a variation on your idea, sampling from a hard circle distribution via e.g. Metropolis sampling, which is quite close to the first application of the [Metropolis algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) in the [original paper](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=metropolis+rosenbluth+1953&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5) by Metropolis and Rosenbluth in statistical mechanics!

I'll try to give an example of how this could look in Mathematica code when i find the time.

Comment: Very helpful answer! Thank you! I learn a lot of new (to me:-)!) things.

Comment: You're welcome! If i find the time, i'll try to implement an example for the Metropolis approach.

Comment: Ok! From what I read I understood that it is not something trivial:-)!

Comment: I seem to remember yveltukov having an implementation of the Metropolis algorithm somewhere…

Comment: @J.M. I implemented it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32540/4678)

Comment: @ybeltukov, that's it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative count based on image processing.

```
g2d2 = Graphics[{Disk[#, r] & /@ pts, Circle[{1/2, 1/2}, {2/5, 1/2}]},
                 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
img = g2d2 // Rasterize;
c = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@img];

sel = SelectComponents[
   c, {"AdjacentBorderCount", "Area"}, #1 == 0 && 50 < #2 < 1000 &];
```

> [image]

```
Length@ComponentMeasurements[sel , "Count"]
```

> 70

Comment: Thanks! Which version of Mma do you use? I cannot obtain the same image.

Comment: v10 but you should add _sel // Colorize_

Comment: Ok! It works great!