# Wolfram alpha algorithm for geometric packing in 2D

Tags: geometry, wolfram-alpha-queries, packing

Is there any way to gain access to the algorithm that wolfram alpha uses? More specifically, I want to pack small circles in hex and square patters in a larger cicle (https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/GeometricPackingIn2D.html), but wolfram alpha only does this up to a number of 1,000.

Comment: Realted demonstration project: [Circles Packed in a Circle](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CirclesPackedInACircle/). Disclaimer: there is no algorithm there, only plain list of circle positions up to 100 circles. See also [(99580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99580) for hexagonal packing approximation.

Comment: Yeah, the code for that one is oddly unsatisfying.  I don't know if someone here has access to the methods used by alpha, I suspect it's off-topic for this site.  You would have better luck rephrasing the question along the lines of "How can I use Mathematica to find the densest packing of _ circles in _ shape?"  Even better if you can give it a shot yourself and ask for improvements to the code.  [Some of these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=packing+circles) might be relevant.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not interested in the densest packing of circles. I'm interested in the required radius to pack N circles in square and hex patterns.