# Randomly distributed circles inside an annulus

Tags: plotting, graphics, discretization

With the following code:

```
findPoints = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {low, _Real}, {high, _Real}, {minD, _Real}},
    Block[{data = RandomReal[{low, high}, {1, 2}], k = 1, rv, temp}, 
    While[k < n, rv = RandomReal[{low, high}, 2];
     temp = Transpose[Transpose[data] - rv];
     If[Min[Sqrt[(#.#)] & /@ temp] > minD, data = Join[data, {rv}];
      k++;];];
    data]];

npts = 150;
r = 0.03;
minD = 2.2 r;
low = 0;
high = 1;

SeedRandom[159]
pts = findPoints[npts, low, high, minD];
g2d = Graphics[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.4], 
    EdgeForm@Directive[Thickness[0.004], Black], Disk[#, r] & /@ pts},
    PlotRange -> All, Background -> Lighter@Blue];

d1 = Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.5];
d2 = Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.3];
annulus = RegionDifference[d1, d2];

mask2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
     MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .02}] &@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[annulus];
r2d2 = DiscretizeGraphics[g2d, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
inside2 = RegionIntersection[r2d2, mask2]
```

I can produce (pseudo)randomly distributed circles inside an annulus.
[image]

I have two questions. The first is a ridiculous one: How can we modify the color (e.g. `Red`) of the `DiscretizeGraphics` output.

The second one is not a tricky one. I want the circles to have random radius. Any ideas of how can I achieve that?

For References about above codes see the question:

[find the maximum number of not intersecting circles inside an ellipse](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99580/find-the-maximum-number-of-not-intersecting-circles-inside-an-ellipse)

and references therein.

Comment: Do they all have to fit inside the annulus?

Comment: Yes, they should.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40334/generating-visually-pleasing-circle-packs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Far from efficient, but we can adapt the Neat Example from the [`RegionDisjoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint.html#1051301794) ref page. Note that a non-uniform distribution of radii would probably speed things up.

```
outerReg = Annulus[];

randomBall[dim_, reg_] := (
  While[
    !RegionWithin[reg, ball = Ball[RandomPoint[reg], RandomReal[{1/15, 1/6}]]],
    (* spin *)
  ];
  ball
)

appendDisjointBall[dim_][reg : Ball[pts_, rs_]] :=
  Block[{ball = randomBall[dim, outerReg]}, 
    While[! RegionDisjoint[ball, reg],
      ball = randomBall[dim, outerReg]
    ];
    Ball[Append[pts, #1], Append[rs, #2]] & @@ ball
  ]

disjointBalls[n_, dim_] := 
 Nest[appendDisjointBall[dim], List /@ randomBall[dim, outerReg], n - 1]

n = 40;
scene2D = disjointBalls[n, 2];

Graphics[{
  {EdgeForm[Black], GrayLevel[.9], Annulus[]}, 
  {EdgeForm[Black], Thread[{RandomColor[Hue[_], n], Thread[scene2D]}]}
}]
```

[image]