# 3D Figure with Cylinders and Spheres

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to draw a figure in 3D where I have a large cylinder inside which there are:

a) smaller cylinders parallel to the larger cylinder that contains them, like in the image below (taken from: [How to draw cylinders inside a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99345/how-to-draw-cylinders-inside-a-cylinder))

[image]

b) randomly distributed spheres that "break" the small cylinders. Occasionally these sphere may appear also on the surface of the main cylinder. I am also ok to place the sphere manually (rather than randomly)

I am looking for suggestion on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.3], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]},
  {Opacity[0.4], 
   Table[If[x^2 + y^2 <= .9^2, 
     Cylinder[{{x, y, -1}, {x, y, 1}}, 0.1]], {x, -1, 1, .2}, {y, -1, 
     1, .2}]}
  , Table[pos = RandomReal[{-.9, .9}, 3]; 
   If[pos[[1 ;; 2]].pos[[1 ;; 2]] <= .9^2, Sphere[pos, 0.1]], 100]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is close to what I am looking for. How to randomize the x-y position of the cylinders without having them overlap? (like in the figure above)

Answer (score 2):

```
outerradius = 1.0;
seeds = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, outerradius], 3000];
radius = .05;
results = Reap[
    While[Length[seeds] > 2,
     (* pick a point and remove all others within radius *)
     {{point}, seeds} = TakeDrop[seeds, 1];
     seeds = Select[seeds, EuclideanDistance[#, point] > 2 radius &];
     Sow[point];
     ]
    ][[2, 1]];
height = 1.0;
cylinders = 
  Cylinder[{Append[#, 0], Append[#, height]}, radius] & /@ results;
Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0.001}, {0, 0, height - 0.001}}, 
   outerradius + radius], Gray, Opacity[1], cylinders}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

Unfortunately I can't get the clipping of the cylinders at the edges. It is very slow to do a `RegionUnion` of all the cylinders and then `RegionIntersection` this bundle with the outer cylinder to chop the edges off. You'd be better off doing this in more optimized 3D software capable of boolean CSG operations.

[image: wires in core]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you create non overlapping random circles inside a unit circles. Take care not to create too many circles, because if the unit circle is filled, the function will search forever:

```
oldpos = {};
newpos[] := (While[(t = RandomReal[{-.9, .9}, 2]; t.t > 0.9^2) || ( 
     Min[Norm[# - t] & /@ oldpos] < 0.2)]; AppendTo[oldpos, t]; t)
Graphics[Table[Circle[newpos[], 0.1], {40}]]
```

[image]